# Disable Database Update Required ? break my website

Tags: database, updates, automatic-updates

Im having an issue if i want to login to the dashboard, it needs a "Database Update Required"

I'd like to disable it, because once it update the Database, if I go to any post of single-pages, it display all my post in loop . .. .   If i recover my database before this update - everything is working correctly.

Any Idea where is this coming from ? or how to disable this update require ?

It will be greatfull,

Thank you for your time,

Comment: The database message appears when WordPress core has been upgraded – if your single post pages no longer display correctly, it's likely there is a problem with a plugin or your theme as a result of the WordPress upgrade.  But the database does *need* to be updated to work properly with the new version of WordPress, so it's not something you should try and turn off.

Answer (score 2):

If you get that Database update message, looks like WordPress may have updated.

Probably you want to turn automatic updates off.

### Simply do:

1 - Restore your db where it works ok

2 - Add this to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

3 - Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you Pieter,

I've add in my wp-config this line of code, unfortunatly, when i try to connect to dashboard, it still asking me to Update the Database :( :( DO you know any other solutissn by any chance ?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it by changing the db value in `wp_options` table and it works like a charm

Comment: Glad you solved the problem for now - just note though that this may cause issues in the future, because you've set the database version to a version that it hasn't actually been upgraded to.